# Кнопка в html без ссылки

Tags: html, android-studio, парсер

есть на сайте кнопка без ссылки, на сколько я понимаю это ссылка на саму кнопку или какой-то параметр который передает эта строка (если не так то поправьте)
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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 как ее расшифровать?
Пишу парсер новостей с сайта и нужно нажимать эту кнопку что бы листать страницы, не пойму куда копать.
Вот ссылка https://www.elitedangerous.com/ru-RU/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/galnet

Answer (score 1):

Это на самом деле картинка закодированная в base64, а не ссылка

Comment: А какой принцип работы у кнопки? Скрипт?

Comment: Судя по картинке, возврат назад в моб. версии сайта